# Get all video id's from YouTube playlist

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm working on an app that shows YouTube video's from one of my own YouTube playlists. I'm using the YouTube Android API to get this done. I use YouTubeThumbnailView to show the video's, I can of course get the playlist in one YouTubeThumbnailView, but I'm looking for a way to get all the video's from the playlist and store them in a string array so I can create a ListView to show all video's.

So the only thing I need are the ID's, then I can get this working. I looked at the [Video Wall](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications#Video_Wall) demo but can't find what I need, beside that it FC on my Nexus 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops! beat you to it :-)

[Link to Blog](http://blog.blundellapps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/)

[image: list of video's]

You need to parse the JSON array data and get the correct string.

Something like this:

```
 // For further information about the syntax of this request and JSON-C
 // see the documentation on YouTube http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc.html

  // Get are search result items
  JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("items");


        // Create a list to store are videos in
        List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();
        // Loop round our JSON list of videos creating Video objects to use within our app
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // The title of the video
            String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
            // The url link back to YouTube, this checks if it has a mobile url
            // if it doesnt it gets the standard url
            String url;
            try {
                url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("mobile");
            } catch (JSONException ignore) {
                url = jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
            }
            // A url to the thumbnail image of the video
            // We will use this later to get an image using a Custom ImageView
            // Found here http://blog.blundellapps.com/imageview-with-loading-spinner/
            String thumbUrl = jsonObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("sqDefault");

            // Create the video object and add it to our list
            videos.add(new Video(title, url, thumbUrl));
        }
```

Comment: Hi your tutorial is Awesome , But it showing only 25 Videos list , But I wan to Get remaining Video list  also , please tell me how i can achive ?

Comment: Go here https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/view_youtube_jsonc_responses